# Eiffel: how do I set the command line arguments of an autotest?

Tags: eiffel

Some of my tests needs something like

```
{EXECUTION_ENVIRONMENT}.arguments.separate_character_option_value ('l')
```

to be attached (not Void), how do I set commandline arguments to eiffel autotest?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no support to run Autotest from the command line and pass arguments, we are looking into it.

So, for now, It's possible to launch test cases from the command line using something like

`ec -config testing.ecf -tests`

but there is no way to filter test cases or even pass command line arguments.

But there is a workaround

You can set environment variables before to run the test cases from the command line or EiffelStudio IDE.

1. Define all the environment variables that you need to mimic the arguments
   `export ARGUMENT_C=my_value` or `set ARGUMENT_C=my_value`.
2. Call the test cases from the command line or IDE
   `ec -config testing.ecf -tests`
3. The test cases that need to get access to these values need to do something like this

   `if attached {EXECUTION_ENVIRONMENT}.get ("ARGUMENT_C") as l_val then
    -- do something
   end`

Hope this helps